# SwiftUI: XCode Preview not showing localized strings

Tags: xcode, swiftui, localization

In the current XCode version (14.3), localized strings are not shown in preview, instead the key is shown. They show in Simulator and on device though. Can someone confirm this behaviour or am I missing a setting or so?

Example
Localized.strings (de): `"price" = "Preis";`

Code:

```
Text("price")
```

Preview*:
price

Simulator / device:
Preis

*) For the preview I am using:

```
ContentView()
        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "de"))
```

as described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/previewing-localizations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue and I fixed it by cleaning the build folder. Command+Shift+K or via the menu bar: Product -> Clean Build Folder

Comment: I think this is the solution, as I did the clean build folder a few days ago on this particular project, but I didn't try the preview different language thing. Now I tried it and it works. Even having multiple languages shown works:

*****    

ForEach(["en", "de"], id:  \.self) { localeId in
        MainView()
            .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: localeId))
        }    *****

Answer (score -1):

```
extension String {
func localized(with arg:[CVarArg] = [])->String{
        return String(format:NSLocalizedString(self, comment:""), arguments: arg)
    }
}
```

Try this extension for your string

Comment: Where do I put this extension?

Comment: I placed that into a separate "Extensions.swift" file, but it didn't change anything, still not working

Comment: Text("price".localized())  use this extension like that

Comment: Have you tested this? Does not work for me ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).